# Flex Datagrid item renderer DateField, Combobox Issue help !

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, itemrenderer

1) Using datefield as item renderer in flex

I am dynamically creating datagrid and its columns. like

```
dataGridColumn=new DataGridColumn();
dataGridColumn.dataField="invoiceDTO.invoiceDate";// I read this value from XML
dataGridColumn.editorDataField="selectedDate";
dataGridColumn.itemRenderer=new ClassFactory(DateFieldRenderer);
dataGridColumn.rendererIsEditor=true;
```

But when UI is generated i get the error invoiceDTO.invoiceDate not found on the TestDTO

```
//Test DTO

public class TestDTO
{
 public var invoiceDTO:InvoiceDTO;
}
```

My objective is my dataField should be binded with datafield inside the datagrid.How can i do it in actionscript

2) I need to present combobox as item renderer. (same like case 1). But how can i assign dataprovider in the
combobox which is present inside the datagrid.

FYI this needs to be done in actionscript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the first part of question. You can't use complex expressions in `dataField` parameter. To display a custom label it is better to use [`labelFunction`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/dataGridClasses/DataGridColumn.html#labelFunction).

What about the second part you should read [official documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ca3.html). There is a sample of creating custom ActionScript item renderers. To be short you can operate `data` property within item renderer to have access to a current element of data provider.